# Array Formula for running column minimum excluding above rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, cumulative-sum

So I have a spreadsheet with a very long series of numbers in a single column. I'd like to have a second column next to it that shows the lowest value contained in the first column, excluding any rows above.

Right now I've accomplished this by using a formula in each row of the second column [ ie: `=MIN($I2:I)` ], but I'd rather avoid having a formula in every row. Is there a way to accomplish this using a single Array Formula?

Comment: Please choose either excel or google sheets, they are different enough that the answers might not work across platforms.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jmcljNZh9VFzl4fUQAbdouJDc1VrAGbwA9pNNIAwxVc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT({""; 
 REPT("×99999", ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)-1)))}&"×"&TEXTJOIN("×", 1, 
 INDEX(SORT({INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)))}, 2, 0)
 ,,1)), "×"), COUNTA(A1:A), COUNTA(A1:A))), "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 "min(Col"&ROW(A1:A)&")", ))&"")), "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RYhqkYLNfga_c6HDvCtdBAP_Q40VHEgf6fEpBL0JO-Q/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thanks! That's super helpful!

Comment: Is there a way I can start it on Row 2? I use the top row as a header row, but when I change "A1:A" to "A2:A" it breaks

Comment: from row 2 it would be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT({""; 
 REPT("×99999", ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A))))}&"×"&TEXTJOIN("×", 1, 
 INDEX(SORT({INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1), ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1))}, 2, 0)
 ,,1)), "×"), COUNTA(A2:A)+1, COUNTA(A2:A)+1)), "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 "min(Col"&ROW(A1:A)&")", ))&"")), "select Col2"))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx8ot.png